# How to make a table showing the AUC and 95% of the AUC for multiple variables

Tags: r, gt

I am trying to make a table like the following table but with multiple rows, each with a variable and the respective AUC and 95% CI.

[image]

I was able to create the above table using this code but I am not sure how to add the multiple variables or if there is a simpler way to do it. Apologies if this is a basic question, I am quite new to R.

```
Table_AUC <- 
{data.frame(
    Characteristic = 'Average Diastolic BP',
    "Area under curve" = round(auc(roc1),2), 
    "Confidence interval" =
        paste(as.character(round(ci.auc(roc1), 2))[c(1, 3)], collapse = " - "),
    check.names = FALSE)} %>%
  gt()

Table_AUC
```

Comment: Could you edit this question to be [reproducible](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5963269/12109788)?

Comment: Wrap your code to perform the analysis and create the table in a function.  Use the function in a call to `lapply`.  Bind the output from `lapply` with `bind_rows` (if using the tidyverse) or `rbind`.  In the absence of *reproducible* example, you'll probably have to figure out the details yourself.